# How do I STOP model data appearing in the URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

How can I pass a viewmodel to a view without the model's data showing up in the URL?

```
public ActionResult MyView(MyModel model)
{
    model.memberId = "Secret Id"
    return View("MyView", model)
}
```

URL shows up as

```
http://localhost:1234/MyView?memberId=Secret Id
```

The data is not critically secret but having it show up in the URL is not really acceptable.

Comment: When performing a GET request you do not really have a choice and using POST / ajax everywhere to avoid adding it the URL when available in the client is not practical. You could always use some other token instead of the Secret Id that can be reversed on the server-side.

Comment: If you want to store a userId you should be storing in your session (on the server), if you don't the client can always guess. Never trust the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you are up to, you should never set anything secret in a viewmodel - because the viewmodel is as the name says to be seen...

But to answer your question: To avoid the memberId occuring in the url you can submit your form by post - but that is of course not secure as well.

You should better store that in the session for example.

Comment: Thanks Marc. What I'm doing is passing member details so that they can be displayed on the next View, so it is not imperative that they're invisible but i don't want people to get member details by simply looking at the browser history.

Comment: In addition, submitting py POST stil populates the URL.

Comment: That shouldn't be. Please post your view and the link/form submit where you request the page as well.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, view models are exactly that - models for your view. You should never store any data in a view model that should not be exposed to the client in one shape or form (whether it be a hidden form value, part of the url or in an ajax call).

If you really need data to be secret, and you want to pass it between actions, use TempData, or the ASPNet Session. That way, it goes nowhere near the client.

I wrote a CAPTCHA generator that uses TempData to store the actual CAPTCHA string, as sending it to the client would mean that any automated system would be able to read the string. I'd recommend using TempData over the session, though, as it's only persisted for one request - whereas the session needs managing by yourself.

```
TempData["MyDataIdentifier"] = "MyObjectOrValue";
```